# Custom "statusMsg" not working as expected

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

After adding the following adaptive authentication script, if the username is not according to the format I should be getting the custom status message saying, `Access Denied, invalid username format.` But instead I get the default status message, `Something went wrong during the authentication process. Please try signing in again.`

```
function onLoginRequest(context) {
    executeStep(1, {
        onSuccess: function(context) {
            var user = context.currentKnownSubject;
            if(user!= null && user.username != null && !user.username.equals('')) {
                Log.info("username: " + user.username);
            } else {
                sendError('',{'status':'AUTHENTICATION USERNAME ERROR', 'statusMsg': 'Access denied, invalid username format.'});
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In addition, I get the following error in the `wso2carbon.log` file as well.

```
TID: [-1234] [authenticationendpoint] [2022-10-05 15:44:12,715] [37951f7d-8240-48d4-ad4f-1d4c8a6a3ec4] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.AuthContextAPIClient} - Sending GET request to URL : https://dev.wso2istemp.com/api/identity/auth/v1.1/data/AuthenticationError/0b0efc37-819d-4b39-85b2-517126c3c9cb, failed. java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://dev.wso2istemp.com/api/identity/auth/v1.1/data/AuthenticationError/0b0efc37-819d-4b39-85b2-517126c3c9cb
...
org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.AuthContextAPIClient.getContextProperties(AuthContextAPIClient.java:70)
        at org.apache.jsp.retry_jsp._jspService(retry_jsp.java:194)
...
org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
...
org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.filter.AuthenticationEndpointFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationEndpointFilter.java:190)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
...
```

The `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` configurations for `[server]` are as follows.

```
[server]
hostname = "dev.wso2istemp.com"
node_ip = "127.0.0.1"
base_path = "https://$ref{server.hostname}:${carbon.management.port}"
```

What is the reason for the following issue in the `wso2carbon.log` and why the custom status message is not shown properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the adaptive authentication script is running, the values are passed to the Identity Server(IS) encrypted. In above case, the encrypted data chunk is passed to the IS,

`https://dev.wso2istemp.com/api/identity/auth/v1.1/data/AuthenticationError/24e56d99-9494-4989-a3e2-4008b73ebd9b`

with the last segment of the URL is being the data chunk. When the server tries to get that data chunk with a GET request, `java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL` which is the code for unauthorized is thrown. Since that data chunk is not properly received, the default status message is shown instead of the custom status message. The steps to resolve this are given below.

1. First clarify whether the `dev.wso2istemp.com` which you were using is not mapped with the `localhost` in `/etc/hosts` file.
2. Go to `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` file and check for the following configuration `[identity.auth_framework.endpoint]` and check whether the mutual SSL is set to false via `mutual_ssl_manager_enabled=false`
3. If so, enable that by commenting the `mutual_ssl_manager_enabled=false`, since using mutual SSL is recommended for IS. If you go to the `<IS_HOME>/repository/resources/conf/default.json file`, you can notice that the default value for `mutual_ssl_manager_enabled` is `true`
4. In a multi-node situation, the above error can occur if the mutual SSL is not enabled, If that does not resolves the issue, then you have to check whether the `internal_hostname` has been set properly so that the internal API calls are being sent properly.
5. To do that, if you have not added the following configuration to `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` file, you can check whether it has been properly applied to the `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml` by checking for `<ServerHostName>localhost</ServerHostName>`

```
[server]
internal_hostname="localhost"
```

6. If you are using a multi-node deployment, this `localhost` value should be added to the SAN for the certificate when the certificate is generated (`-ext SAN=dns:localhost`)

```
keytool -genkey -alias newcert -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore newkeystore.jks -dname "CN=dev.wso2istemp.com, OU=Is,O=Wso2,L=SL,S=WS,C=LK" -storepass mypassword -keypass mypassword -ext SAN=dns:localhost
```

7. But if you are using a single node you can add the following configuration to the `deployment.toml` and check whether it resolves things. (In single node case the `internal_hostname` should be similar to `hostname`)

```
[server]
hostname = "dev.wso2istemp.com"
internal_hostname = "dev.wso2istemp.com"
```

8. If that is not working[https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/11878] then go to `<IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/authenticationendpoint/WEB-INF/web.xml` and uncomment the following commented snippet.

```
<!--context-param>
    <param-name>AuthenticationRESTEndpointURL</param-name>
    <param-value>https://localhost:9443/api/identity/auth/v1.1/</param-value>
</context-param-->
```

9. This might route the `internal_hostname` being reflected on the request since the internal API calls are blocked when `hostname` of the server being replaced instead of the `internal_hostname` for the internal API calls(`https://dev.wso2istemp.com/api/identity/auth/v1.1/data/AuthenticationError/24e56d99-9494-4989-a3e2-4008b73ebd9b`).